# MATLAB: Plot multiple lines with different color intensity per line

Tags: matlab, graph, colors, weighted-graph

I want to plot a series of lines, with each line being colored according to a certain weight. I stumbled accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28189766), but the problem is, I am plotting multiple things on one graph, where only one of the plot statements should be color weighted.

I'm using `hold on; hold off;`, but I only see the last graph. Thus, the final result is, I only see the color weighted plot statements, but not the other plot statements that should be plotted due to `hold on; hold off;`.

Here is my code, where `upper*p` is an n x 1 vector representing the intensity of each of the n lines:

```
cmap = colormap;
con_min = min(upper*p)*25;
con_max = max(upper*p)*25;
ind_upper = ceil((size(cmap,1)-1)*((con_min:con_max)'-con_min+1)/(con_max-con_min));

subplot(2,3,2);
hold on;
    title('Gains');
    set(gca,'ColorOrder',cmap(ind_upper,:),'NextPlot','replacechildren');
    plot(flat','c');
    plot(lower','c');
    plot(upper');
    set(gca, 'xtick',1:labelFreq:num_tickers, 'xticklabel', tickers(1:4:num_tickers));
    ylabel('bp change on day');
    colorbar;
    caxis([con_min con_max]);
hold off;
```

It seems the "upper" part is plotted correctly according to the color weights, but the "flat" and "lower" graphs do not show. I think it's because the set(gca,...) statement is causing the graphs to reset.

Comment: Can you actually show us the code you're talking about? If you call `hold off`, the next plot will clear everything

Comment: Sorry, just added the code.

Comment: Why do you set the `NextPlot` to `'replaceChildren'`? You know that's the same as calling `hold off` right?

Comment: I believe @Suever is recommending that you replace `set(gca,'ColorOrder',cmap(ind_upper,:),'NextPlot','replacechildren');` with `set(gca,'ColorOrder',cmap(ind_upper,:));`

Comment: `flat` and `lower` are getting potted with the "cyan" color. Is that what you intended?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you gave a complete example, demonstrating your problem.  I can't run your code above, and have it generating anything.  So, I am having a hard time understanding what you are expecting to see, vs. what you are seeing.  If you think the set(gca... commands are problematic, remove them, and see if it helps....